# Why I get Corrupted module compiling message while trying to put derived types in a module?

Tags: fortran95, flang

I am learning how to distribute the code across modules in Fortran 95.

I have the following code which intends to use two derived types:

**file_parser_2.f95**

```
program file_parser_2

        use data_model_2
        
        implicit none

        ! -------------------
        ! VARIABLE DEFINITION
        ! -------------------
        integer                         :: i, io_result
        integer                         :: lines_read
        type(type1_record)              :: line_read
        type(timestamp_record)          :: timestamp_read
        
        ! -------------------
        ! READ RECORDS
        ! -------------------
        lines_read = 0
        do 

                ! READ LINE TO line_read IF AVAILABLE
                read(*,*,iostat=io_result) line_read
                if (io_result /= 0) exit
        
                ! PARSE TIMESTAMP
                timestamp_read%year = line_read%year
                timestamp_read%month = line_read%month
                timestamp_read%day = line_read%day
                timestamp_read%hour = line_read%hour
                timestamp_read%minute = line_read%minute
                timestamp_read%second = line_read%second
                
                ! DO OTHER STUFF
                ! TBC

        end do

end program
```

The program does nothing, just reads input and process it according to those fields. It is intentionally stripped down to cover the specific question.

As those derived types will be used in different modules and potentially in different programs, I have put them in a separate module named  `data_model`.

**data_model_2.f95**

```
module data_model_2
        
        ! -------------------
        ! TYPE DEFINITION
        ! -------------------
        type :: type1_record
                integer                 :: month
                integer                 :: day
                integer                 :: year
                integer                 :: hour
                integer                 :: minute
                integer                 :: second
                integer                 :: value1
                integer                 :: value2
        end type
        type :: timestamp_record
                integer                 :: year
                integer                 :: month
                integer                 :: day
                integer                 :: hour
                integer                 :: minute
                integer                 :: second
        end type

end module
```

I try to compile them but I get Corrupted module error:

```
$ flang file_parser_2.f95
F90-F-0004-Corrupt or Old Module file ./data_model_2.mod (file_parser_2.f95: 5)
F90/x86-64 FreeBSD Flang - 1.5 2017-05-01: compilation aborted
$
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you recompile `data_model_2.f95` before `file_parser_2.f95`?

Comment: Please try to avoid asking those additional parts (about `contains` and `implicit none`) in the same question: it would be better/more helpful to other people if questions consider just one aspect. (Note also that with `contains` you get different answers under [tag:fortran] and [tag:fortran95], so please be sure whether you are asking about Fortran 90, Fortran 95 or Fortran.)

Comment: I totally misunderstood the process I have to do `flang -c data_model_2.f95` and that generates both `data_model_2.o` and `data_model_2.mod` and then I can compile `file_parser_2.f95`

Comment: I edited the question keeping it only the compilation issue and move the rest to a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636893/when-do-i-have-to-use-contains-in-a-module