# When do I have to use CONTAINS in a module?

Tags: fortran

I have the following module defined:

```
module data_model_2

        implicit none

        ! -------------------
        ! TYPE DEFINITION
        ! -------------------
        type :: type1_record
                integer                 :: month
                integer                 :: day
                integer                 :: year
                integer                 :: hour
                integer                 :: minute
                integer                 :: second
                integer                 :: value1
                integer                 :: value2
        end type
        type :: timestamp_record
                integer                 :: year
                integer                 :: month
                integer                 :: day
                integer                 :: hour
                integer                 :: minute
                integer                 :: second
        end type

end module
```

I have seen that `modules` shall use the clause `contains`. Is the clause needed when the module contains only derived types definition?

If so, where shall it be included, after or before the `implicit none`?

If the module would include also functions or procedures, shall the derived types definitions be before or after `contains` clause?

I am interested in knowing how this works in Fortran 95 and Fortran 03.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `contains` statement says that what follows are *internal subprograms* or *module subprograms*.  Only those things may appear between `contains` and the `end` of the module.

Before Fortran 2008 it was not allowed to have an "empty contains" section: if you have no module subprograms in Fortran 90, 95, 2003 then you may not have `contains`.  In Fortran 2008+ you may have it, although it is not required, without them.

`contains` is essentially the last thing allowed in a module: all module-scope definitions which aren't internal/module subprograms must be before.  An `implicit` statement must be very early in the module scope: only the module statement, `use` and `import` (in those supported rare cases) may preceed it.